# How to set HANDLE in a function ? (C)

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
    HANDLE h = NULL;
    init(h);
    dosomething(h);
```

How do I set "h" in the init function in order to use it in the dosomething function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the address of `h` to `init()` as C passes by value:

```
void init(HANDLE* a_h)
{
    *a_h = ...; /* some handle. */
}
```

and invoked:

```
init(&h);
if (h)
{
    dosomething(h);
    CloseHandle(h);
}
```

In addition to passing the address of the `HANDLE` into `init()`, depending on action required in event of failure to acquire a `HANDLE`, you may also pass in the address of `DWORD` to store the last error in the event of failure to make this information available to the caller:

```
void init(HANDLE* a_h, DWORD* a_last_error)
{
    *a_h = /* code to acquire handle. */;
    if (NULL == *a_h) *a_last_error = GetLastError();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to passing the address as many have suggested, I would recommend *returning* the handle from the function, instead. It makes for somewhat cleaner code:

```
HANDLE h = init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the address of the handle, not the handle itself. Review call-by-reference and call-by-value. You're currently calling by value, so any changes made by `init()` are local only.

What you want is something like:

```
void init(HANDLE *h)
{
    *h = something;
}

....

    ...
    HANDLE H=NULL;
    init(&h);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `init(&h)` instead of `init(h)`

And define `init` as

```
void init(HANDLE * h)
{ /* do whatever */ }
```

Then the changes will be visible in the main too.

Also a small note: You might need to pass the pointer/address of `HANDLE` to the `dosomething()` too (depending on what you want to accomplish in there)

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on earlier answers.  To use data hiding you'll want to define your handle as a void pointer outside the implementation and the real structure inside, so only the implementation can see what the structure is made of.

In your header file:

```
typedef void * HANDLE;

void init(HANDLE *h);
void dosomething(HANDLE h);
void destroy(HANDLE *h);
```

The implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int contents;
} * HANDLE;

void init(HANDLE *h) {
    *h = (HANDLE)malloc(sizeof *h);
    (*h)->contents = 2;
}

void dosomething(HANDLE h) {
    printf("Contents are: %d\n", h->contents);
}

void destroy(HANDLE *h) {
    free(*h);
    *h = NULL;
}
```

And the calling function:

```
HANDLE h = NULL;

init(&h);
dosomething(h);
destroy(&h);
```

Don't forget to include your header file.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Unfortunately I can only use static things no malloc for Handles.